# How to extract column data from a text in python (regex)

Tags: python, regex, text, extract

Let's say we have text within which column header are stored in the form:

```
{|
|+ The table's caption
! scope="col" width="20"style="background-color:#cfcfcf;"align="center" | Column header 1
! scope="col" width="20"style="background-color:#ff55ff;"align="center" | Column header 2
! scope="col" | Column header 3
|-
! scope="row" | Row header 1
| Cell 2 || Cell 3
|-
! scope="row" | Row header A
| Cell B
| Cell C
|}
```

How can I extract all the columns ([**Column header 1**, **Column header 2**, **Column header 3**]) from the text in python?

```
re.findall('*! scope="col" |', text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

But it's not doing the job.

https://regex101.com/r/PLKREz/6

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: Are you scraping this from the web, or is this text given to you to use?

Comment: @Wintro this is from the wikipedia articles and my task is to extract the columns from the tables ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the substrings after the last `|` in a line with `scope="col"`:

```
import re

data = """
{|
|+ The table's caption
! scope="col" width="20"style="background-color:#cfcfcf;"align="center" | Column header 1
! scope="col" width="20"style="background-color:#ff55ff;"align="center" | Column header 2
! scope="col" | Column header 3
|-
! scope="row" | Row header 1
| Cell 2 || Cell 3
|-
! scope="row" | Row header A
| Cell B
| Cell C
|}"""

print(re.findall(r'scope="col".*?\| ([^|]+)$', data, re.MULTILINE))
```

Prints:

```
['Column header 1', 'Column header 2', 'Column header 3']
```